# Redis Cache throws OOM Error with volitile-lru

Tags: caching, redis, lru

For debugging we have set Redis to volitile-lru and maxmemory of 10mb

We are using Redis for HTTP Caching in an Ecommerce shop - when there are parallel Requests on a Page the error:

```
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'
```

appears. Shouldn't this be avoided by setting the maxmemory-policy to volitile-lru ? Is redis not fast enought to set the memory free and set the new one (each request has about 200-600kb)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

`volatile-lru: evict keys by trying to remove the less recently used (LRU) keys first, but only among keys that have an expire set, in order to make space for the new data added.`

It seems like your keys might not have an expiration. If thats the case, you might want to consider using `allkeys-lru` as your eviction policy.

You can also use `INFO stats` to see if `evicted_keys` has a value greater than zero.